# Can RedQuits be made to work with Chrome and OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, window-manager

I am used to [RedQuits](http://www.carsten-mielke.com/redquits.html) as I like Chrome to behave the same way under different OSes (i.e. closing last window quits application), but I can't make it work on a new iMac with Lion. Others have similar issues with [RedQuits and Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71022/chrome-is-not-working-properly-with-redquits).

RedQuits seems to work in general, but as soon as I enable "Quit only when 1 window is left for that app" Chrome starts to close last window instead of quitting (as if it has a hidden window somewhere that interfere). Anyone managed to use RedQuits with Chrome & "1 window mode" or maybe there are any alternatives to this app?

Comment: The problem only occurs in Chrome I assume? Did you already contact the developer (there's a link on the website)?

Comment: Yip, seems to be limited to Chrome only. Haven't contacted developer yet, but planning to do it.